# Web Server - timeout with specific response?

Tags: apache, nginx, timeout

We are developing a service that needs to respond within 50ms AND it needs a good SLA, i.e. must always be live and responsive.

Question - is it possible to set a default response (e.g. respond with blank JSON object) to use in case of web server (nginx or Apache) timeout? If so - how to do this?

I could add this to the application logic but setting it at the server level would be more fail-proof.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`error_page`](http://nginx.org/r/error_page) directive.

E.g.:

```
error_page 502 504 =200 @blank_json;

location @blank_json {
    return 200 "{}";
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you. Maybe you also happen to know how to set timeout in milliseconds (ms) instead of seconds? I know I can limit execution time of request by setting request_terminate_timeout=XXX for php-fpm. But how do I do the same with ms?
The basic idea: "Fail in XXXms with a response code 200 and standard content".

Comment: Try [`fastcgi_read_timeout`](http://nginx.org/r/fastcgi_read_timeout) and [`fastcgi_connect_timeout`](http://nginx.org/r/fastcgi_connect_timeout) in nginx. (e.g. `fastcgi_read_timeout 30ms;`)